# Create a list of classes

Tags: c#, list

I need to create a list of classes. I don`t want to uses "Insert", since the amount of data is small and adding ll data all together might be more readable.
Unfortunatelly I even cant compile the code :

```
List<MyArg> perfTestsArgs = new List<MyArg>(
            { new MyArg("columns","1"),
              new MyArg("rows","1"),
              new MyArg("batch","1"),
              new MyArg("trips","400"),
              new MyArg("strict","true"),
              new MyArg("valueLength","1"),
            }); //<- problematic (why?)
public class MyArg
    {
        public string ArgName { get; set; }
        public string ArgValue { get; set; }

        public PerformanceTestsArg(string argName, string argValue)
        {
            ArgName = argName;
            ArgValue = argValue;
        }
    }
```

I`ll appreciate the advice how to do that correctely

Comment: You can close the parenthasis after List<MyArg>( or remove the parenthasis entirly if you're not passing anything to the constructor. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<MyArg> perfTestsArgs = new List<MyArg>() // <- close the bracket here, or remove () as @Mihai  said
            { new MyArg("columns","1"),
              new MyArg("rows","1"),
              new MyArg("batch","1"),
              new MyArg("trips","400"),
              new MyArg("strict","true"),
              new MyArg("valueLength","1"),
            };
```

more details on initializing objects here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: That's not fair, dude :) You've "stole" my answer to update yours. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Mihai sorry, now it says it was your idea :)

Comment: :)), no biggie. I was just teasing. I don't even think this question deserves an answer. A short comment would be sufficient, as the one provided by Sam, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `()` from `new List<MyArg>`.